# Laravel 5.4 how can I get the sum of the total new applications per month

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have in my application that I will get all the reports of total new application per month.

Here is my applications table structure:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('applications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //$table->increments('id');
        $table->string('application_number')->primary();
        $table->string('applicant_id');
        //$table->string('reference_number', 50);
        $table->string('business_name');
        $table->string('business_nature');
        $table->string('location_street');
        $table->string('location_building')->nullable();
        $table->string('location_barangay');
        $table->string('location_district');
        $table->string('landmarks')->nullable();
        $table->string('owner_fn');
        $table->string('owner_mn')->nullable();
        $table->string('owner_ln');
        $table->string('ar_fn');
        $table->string('ar_mn')->nullable();
        $table->string('ar_ln');
        $table->string('landline')->nullable();
        $table->string('cellphone_number')->nullable();
        $table->string('occupancy_type');
        //$table->string('cluster_no', 50);
        $table->string('land_area')->nullable();
        $table->string('no_floor')->nullable();
        $table->string('floor_area')->nullable();
        $table->string('no_employees')->nullable();
        $table->string('requirements_1')->nullable();
        $table->string('requirements_2')->nullable();
        $table->string('requirements_3')->nullable();
        $table->string('requirements_4')->nullable();
        $table->string('applicant_name');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->string('application_type');
        $table->date('expired_at');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

and here is the code in my controller:

```
public function index()
    {   
        $applications = DB::table('applications')->sum('created_at');
        $inspections = DB::table('for_inspections')->sum('created_at');
        $certifications = DB::table('certification')->sum('created_at');    

        $chart = Charts::multi('bar', 'material')
            // Setup the chart settings
            ->title("Monthly Report")
            // A dimension of 0 means it will take 100% of the space
            ->dimensions(0, 400) // Width x Height
            // This defines a preset of colors already done:)
            ->template("material")
            // You could always set them manually
            // ->colors(['#2196F3', '#F44336', '#FFC107'])
            // Setup the diferent datasets (this is a multi chart)
            ->dataset('New Applications', [5,20,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
            ->dataset('Total Inspection', [15,30,80,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
            ->dataset('Certified', [25,10,40,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
            // Setup what the values mean
            ->labels(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']);
        return view('admin-dashboard.reports_home', ['chart' => $chart]);
    }
```

There is no errors or problem here. I just don't know where to start because I am new in laravel especially in backend using model and controller. So I am looking for help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can manipulate timestamps with `Carbon` to get periodical reports, also use `Query Builder` so it'll be easy to use where conditions. :)

Comment: like these?
$application = DB::table('applications')
                ->whereMonth('created_at', '8')
                ->get(); 

so I will query each and other months and assigned variables to them and display it on the dataset depends on the label?

Comment: You can use `Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();` to get first day of the current month and `Carbon::now()->endOfMonth();` to get the last day.

It also has Days, Weeks, and Years! So it's really helpful.

Comment: So it would be like: $application_aug = DB::table('applications')
                ->whereMonth('created_at', 'Carbon::now()->eightOfMonth();')
                ->count(); like that?

Comment: I'll post an answer so it would look better. :)

Comment: Oh okay thankyou so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a `datefrom` and `dateto` either from your blade or somewhere else, depends on you.

But in this example, it would be from the blade's `select` tag with a name as `period`:

```
<select name="period" id="period" class="form-control">
    <option></option>
    <option>Daily</option>
    <option>Weekly</option>
    <option>Monthly</option>
    <option>Yearly</option>
</select>
```

So it will decide how it will show the reports, whether it'll be Daily, Weekly, Monthly, and Yearly.

Inside the controller, I set an example:

```
            if($period == 'Daily'){
                    $datefrom = Carbon::now()->startOfDay();
                    $dateto = Carbon::now()->endOfDay();
                }
            elseif ($period == 'Weekly') {
                $datefrom = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek();
                $dateto = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek();
            }
            elseif ($period == 'Monthly') {
                $datefrom = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();
                $dateto = Carbon::now()->endOfMonth();
            }
            elseif ($period == 'Yearly'){
                $datefrom = Carbon::now()->startOfYear();
                $dateto = Carbon::now()->endOfYear();   
            }
```

And for the query, it would be something like this:

```
 $orders = DB::table('orders')
            ->whereDate('created_at','>=', $datefrom)
            ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $dateto)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Thankyou! It worked! so you are a Filipino too. I am still student and want to explore and learn more about MVC Frameworks and OOP.

Comment: Glad it worked! Yes, I am a Filipino too, and still a student like you. :D
Keep in touch with stackoverflow. They have decent answers for questions related to Laravel haha.

Comment: Can I add you on facebook? Hahaha